# Exact definition of continuity of $f$ on $A \subseteq \textrm{dom}_f$

Tags: continuity, definition

For $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},$ is there a universal definition of "$f$ is continuous on $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$"?

For example, what about the function $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which takes the value $5$ on $[2,3]$ and the value $0$ on $(-\infty,2)\cup(3,\infty)$?

Clearly $g$ is not continuous at all points in $[2,3]$ as $g$ is discontinuous at $2.$

Clearly $g|_{[2,3]}$ is a continuous function.

Ps. I'm pretty sure I understand stuff logically. Just wondering if there exists an "official" definition? So answers quoting a well-known author such as Rudin or Apostol would be appreciated, thanks [I don't have access to libraries now].

Comment: Check page 25 of [this PDF](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125a/intro_analysis.pdf). "A function $f : A\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on a set $B\subset A$ if it is continuous at every point in $B$."

Comment: @MichaelLee I think the point here is that whether it's continuous at a given point in $B$ might depend on whether we, as we check for continuity, consider the function as $f:A\to \Bbb R$ or $f:B\to \Bbb R$.

Comment: As is made clear in the line I quoted, the function is $f : A\to \mathbb{R}$, and the set is $B\subset A$. In @SphereMr's example, $A = \mathbb{R}$ and $B$ might be $[2, 3]$. As $g : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is not continuous at every point in $[2, 3]$, $g$ is not continuous on $[2, 3]$ (although it _is_ continuous on $(2, 3)$).

Comment: This definition has the advantage that if $f : A\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on subsets $B_1, B_2\subset A$, then $f$ is continuous on $B_1\cup B_2$. If we use the other definition of "continuity on a subset" proposed in the question, then we lose this nice property.

Comment: Thank you for replying, Michael Lee.

Comment: I think overall the definition you gave is best. 

Ps. Although it arguably has the \emph{symbolic} disadvantage that although my function $g$ is not continuous on $[2,3],$ the Mean Value Theorem is applicable to $g$ on $[2,3].$

Comment: Check the [statement of the mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) more carefully: for continuous $f : [a, b]\to \mathbb{R}$ (note the domain of $f$) that is differentiable on $(a, b)$, there is a $c\in (a, b)$ such that $$f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$ If you consider $g|_{[2, 3]} : [2, 3]\to \mathbb{R}$, then it is clear that the mean value theorem holds for $g$ on $[2, 3]$.

Comment: It's all good, cheers. Taking $f$ to have domain $[a,b]$ rather than requiring $f$ to be continuous on $[a,b]$ when formulating the MVT is clever.

Answer (score 0):

Your function $g$ is indeed *not continuous* at $2$.

However, the function $h$ defined on the set $[2,3]$ to be the same as $g$ (in other terms, the *restriction* of $g$ to $[2,3]$), *is* continuous at $2$. This is not a contradiction, because we're considering two different functions.

Here's a quite common definition of continuity for functions taking on real values:

> Let $f$ be defined on a set $A$ of real numbers and let $a\in A$; the function $f$ is said to be *continuous at* $a$ if, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for every $x\in A$ with $|x-a|<\delta$, it holds that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$. The function $f$ is said to be *continuous* if it is continuous at every point of its domain $A$.

Such a definition ensures that restricting the domain of a continuous function yields a continuous function. Your example shows that the restriction of a non continuous function may be continuous.

Note that specifying the domain of the function we want to analyze the continuity of is essential. On the other hand, textbooks may have a slightly different definition, so you need to check the conventions used and stick with them.